# Indicate direction or point to object by gesture of the head

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Indicate direction or point to object by gesture of the head. Visually, it is a short jerk of the head in the said direction. Say a SWAT team leader silently directs his men to go to the left. Would you say "nods at"? There has to be something better.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use use [*jerk*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/jerk):

> He indicated the bedroom with a jerk of his head.

Alternatively you could indeed use [*nod*](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/nod_2):

> I asked where Steve was and she nodded in the direction of the kitchen.

Comment: Yes - 'nod in the direction of', or 'nod towards', not 'nod at' (a location - 'nod at' is fine with an object or person).

Answer (score 0):

you can employ the verb form of ***cock***.

> The man [*cocked*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cock) his head, motioning toward the counter and started walking down the aisle (sentence copied from an online literary magazine straylightmag.com).